# Probability of exactly $k$ returns to the origin of the simple random walk in $2n$ first steps

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

I try to find the probability $p_{n, k}$of the fact that simple symmetric visits the origin exactly $k$ times on the segment $[0, 2n]$, where $n\ge k$.

I tried to solve recurrent formula:
$$p_{n, k} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-k}f_i\cdot p_{n-i, k-1},$$
where $f_i$ is the probability of the fact that the first return get in the point $2i$. But I can't simplify it. As another try I wrote the formula of inclusion-exclusion with an events when random walk visits the origin at the fixed point. But I can't figure it out. May be another simple way exists?

Comment: Considering the generating functions $$P_k(s)=\sum_np_{n,k}s^n\qquad F(s)=\sum_nf_ns^n$$ should yield a relation akin to $$P_k(s)=F(s)P_{k-1}(s)$$ hence, for every $k$, $$P_k(s)=F(s)^k$$ The explicit or implicit nature of the rest depends on the explicit or implicit nature of $F(s)^k$...

Comment: Thank you! I've found that $$F^k(s)=(1-(1-s)^{1/2})^k,$$ but appropriate coefficient in the series for this has a bad view